# Angular issue using BrightCove Player Loader

Tags: angular, brightcove

I followed the instructions to install BrightCove player loader in my Angular 11 application:

```
npm install --save @brightcove/player-loader
```

and then Import in app.Module.ts, and also in the module where I want to use brightcovePlayerLoader

```
import { brightcovePlayerLoader } from '@brightcove/player-loader';
```

but I get this error when building:

```
Error: ./src/app/core/player/player.component.ts 23:8-30
"export 'brightcovePlayerLoader' was not found in '@brightcove/player-loader'
    at --lengthy call stack omitted for brevity--
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Any insights appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was mine - the import should read:

```
import brightcovePlayerLoader from '@brightcove/player-loader';
```

(i.e. without the braces)

Comment: How did you import it in your app.module? I don't know what the import url is

Comment: This is a response to an old comment, but for anyone with the question of importing it - you can create this folder structure in the `src` folder: `@types/@brightcove/player-loader`. Then within the player-loader folder, add an index.d.ts file and put this single line of code: `declare module "@brightcove/player-loader";`